# Elisp: Inserting Comments

Tags: major-mode, comment

I'm trying to write an elisp program that will insert a section header and footer as a comment. For example, if I need a section called "intro" for my LaTeX document, the following would be inserted:

```
%----------BEGIN INTRO----------%



%-----------END INTRO-----------%
```

Similarly, if I need a section called "functions" in my C++ file, the following would be inserted:

```
//----------BEGIN FUNCTIONS----------//



//----------END FUNCTIONS-----------//
```

My trouble is finding a way to identify the comment pattern of the current major mode so that it can be included in the inserted string. Any insight would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you done to try and find an answer before posting this question?

Comment: My research took me to syntax tables and the `comment-dwim` command. My plan was to try to figure out how `comment-dwim` knew what the comment character was in order to make its comment, but that didn't work out. Additionally, I couldn't find anything helpful via the syntax table route. I saw a bunch of stuff for making a syntax table, but nothing on how to extract the comment sequence from it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest the variables `comment-start` and `comment-end` as well as the function `comment-region`.

Comment: Thank you, Stefan! I just used `comment-start` at the beginning of my line, and `comment-end` at the end. While the visual formatting isn't exactly what I had in mind, that can't really be helped, since not all languages have regional comments (LaTeX only has `%` while C has `/*` and `*/`. Nevertheless, it's functionally perfect! Thanks for showing me these helpful variables!